# How do I create a png, combining another image, backgroundcolor and text?

Tags: php, png

I'm trying to create image to present weather data:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");

$place = $_GET['place'];
$temp = $_GET['temp'];
$weather = $_GET['weather'];

$im_width = 150;
$im_height = 150;

$im = @imagecreate($im_width, $im_height);

$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

$weather_im = imagecreatefrompng("images/". $weather .".png");
imagecopy($im, $weather_im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $im_width, $im_height);

$font = 'segoeui.ttf';
$font_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

$temp_font_size = 24;

imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 5, $im_height-10, $font_color, $font, $place);
imagettftext($im, $temp_font_size, 1, $im_width-$temp_font_size, $im_height/2, $font_color, $font, $temp);

imagepng($im, '', 9);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

I got the text, but after adding the other image, 13, there is only background image and that image. Before I did the imagecopy i had the text too :-/

Comment: What other image? What is 13? There is no usage of `$background_color` in posted code.

Comment: $weather = 13, its a actual file: 13.png. Point is after imagecopy I lost the text that was there before i added the imagecopy

Comment: So it works with other images but stops for this particular one?